# Paypal Billing Agreement ID validity

Tags: paypal

I want to know that, however the reference transaction must have occurred within the past 730 days because the Billing Agreement ID may not be available after a two years. So if first transaction is done before expiry lets say after 600 days so the ID will be available until 130 days or it will again available for 730 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the billing agreement id then its valid untill you or your customer cancels it . So its best practice to use the BA id for PayPal transactions .

For direct credit card payment you have to use the transaction id(as BA id is only if some one pays via Paypal).
Whenever you use the reference transaction on an existing transaction, the resulting new transaction id will have the new validity for another 730 days and this way you won't have to worry for 730 days limitation. So it's best to update your database with the latest transaction id whenever you do the reference transaction .

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/#id094TB0Y0J5Z__id094TB4003HS